# In NumPy, larger arrays are created more quickly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, caching, timeit

Is this a cache thing, as timeit suggests?

```
In [55]: timeit a = zeros((10000, 400))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop

In [56]: timeit a = zeros((10000, 500))
The slowest run took 13.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.43 µs per loop
```

Tried to fool it, but it didn't work:

```
In [58]: timeit a = zeros((10000, 500+random.randint(100)))
The slowest run took 13.31 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.35 µs per loop
```

Comment: maybe temporal I get 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.57 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.64 µs per loop running your code the difference is minimal

Comment: Try `ones` instead.  Or add a `fill`.

Comment: This is rather consistent on my machine. using `ones` is slow (3-4ms) in both sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is not caching but that numpy just creates a placeholder instead of the full array. This can be easily verified by monitoring your RAM usage when you do something like this:

```
a = np.zeros((20000, 20000), np.float64)
```

This doesn't allocate 20k*20k*8byte ~ 3GB on my computer (but might be OS-dependant because `np.zeros` uses the C function `calloc`). But be careful because most operations on this array (for example `a += 5`) will immediatly allocate that memory! Make sure you use an appropriate size compared to your RAM so that you'll notice the RAM increase without overusing it.

In the end this just postpones the allocation of the array, as soon as you operate with it the combined timing of allocation and operation should be as expected (linear with the number of elements). It seems you're using IPython so you can use a block-timeit `%%timeit`:

```
%%timeit
a = np.zeros((10000, 400))
a += 10
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 30.3 ms per loop

%%timeit
a = np.zeros((10000, 800))
a += 10
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 60.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Great explanation!! This seems to be it, indeed.

Comment: Note that this placeholder can be actually very good. If I only touch a[0,0] after creating a huge array (say), then it doesn't cost time at all (and doesn't allocate memory for the rest of the array). I wonder if the size threshold is configurable from within python.

Comment: I tried to find the threshold in the numpy source code but haven't found it. Note that it could even be `calloc` which makes this optimization. Either way it will most likely be in a `C` file so no way to easily change it from within python.